# Perl between two string regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have text like that. Value goes to 100.

```
<OPTION value=2>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 - Switchable Glass: A possible medium for Evolvable Hardware (4)</OPTION> 
<OPTION value=3>&nbsp;&nbsp;3 - An Efficient Multi-Objective Evolutionary Algorithm for Combinational Circuit Design (3)</OPTION>
<OPTION value=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;4 - A Background Mismatch Calibration for Capacitive Digital-to-Analog Converters (3)</OPTION>
```

And I want this string for first line

`2 - Switchable Glass: A possible medium for Evolvable Hardware (4)`

But when i use regex, i face error. Because string has "/".

How can i fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show some code on how you are using regex? Also what error are you getting?

Comment: So, you want all the content of the option tags? But you want to exclude entities within the content. Is that the question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex and extract group 1.. i.e. `$1`:

```
<OPTION[^>]*>([^;<]+)<\/OPTION>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cK8/3)

Comment: @karthikmanchala - Thats a pretty good tool that you have used here. Thanks for sharing that. I didnt know about it.

Comment: @karthikmanchala thank you for your help :) but why didn't start value = 10. How can i start value = 1. I don't know so much regex. It's my fault :)

Comment: I dint get you.. I haven't used any 10 or 1 in my regex... Is it that you want any specific values? Update your question...

Answer (score 0):

You can always escape a `/` in your pattern by doing `\/` so that `/` will not have special meaning to perl.

Comment: But when i do that, i can't find whatever i want.

Comment: So what is it about that line that makes it the one you want to match?  Could you edit your question to show us the pattern you're trying to use?

Comment: Actually i want string like what i wrote. But i'm working on this txt. http://pastebin.com/0rrAq1sD